# End of <li> text dropping to next line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with a list that needs to work with mobile. When I shrink the window width down, most li elements shrink with the page but "SETUP" is dropping down. I'm using bootstrap.

```css
.dollar {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  top: 17px;
}

.price {
  font-size: 83px;
  line-height: 1em;
  padding: 0 3px;
  font-weight: 200;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -15px;
}

.price.in.table2 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.price.in.table2 span {
  color: #262626;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>
  <div class="price in table2">
    <sup class="dollar">$</sup>
    <span class="price">5000</span>
    <span class="afterprice">/ ONE-TIME SETUP</span>
  </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: We don't have enough information with the code provided. Can you make a demo that actually shows the issue?

Comment: Better to use `Responsive Font Size`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the whitespace property, but if it doesn't wrap it's going to overflow its container, which is worse from a design perspective. You're better off reducing the font size in a media query so that neither happens at that minimal break point.

Answer (score 2):

you can use in css `white-space: nowrap` for `<li>` or for css class `.price` on `<div>` tag.